# Description of the fibres of a family of morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $S$ be a quasi-projective $k$-variety and $f : X \to S$ be a flat morphism. Suppose that the morphism $f$ factors through a finite surjective morphism $g : X \to \mathbb{P}^1 \times S$ such that for every $s \in S$, $g_s : X_s \to \mathbb{P}^1 \times \{s\}$ is generically étale. Furthermore, we assume that the degrees of the morphisms $g_s$ are constant as $s$ varies along $S$. 
 Let $L$ be a field extension of $k$ and 
  $h : \mathrm{Spec}(L) \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be an $L$-point whose image is the generic point of 
  $\mathbb{P}^1$. The $L$-point $h$ defines a morphism $h_S : \mathrm{Spec}(L) \times S \to \mathbb{P}^1 \times S$. 
  Let $s \in S(k)$ and $S_L := S \times_k L$. 
 Can one show that there exists a Zariski open neighbourhood $U \subset S_L$ of the point 
  $s$ and a monic separable polynomial $P \in \mathcal{O}_{S_L}(U)[T]$ such that if $X_U := X \times_S U$ then
  for every $x \in U(L)$ 
  \begin{align*} 
  X_U \times_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times U} (\mathrm{Spec}(L) \times \{x\}) \simeq \mathrm{Spec}(L[T]/P_x)  
  \end{align*} 
  where $P_x \in L[X]$ is obtained from the polynomial $P$ by evaluating 
  its coefficients at the point $x$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.